Animated series featuring a caped man with a Monocle and a cane?
There was this show, animated series, featuring a man with a monocle and a cane, fighting a group of organized criminals, and he was named something like "Allen Lion"; not sure what the language was, anyone recognizes this??

Any idea on the year? And was he definitely a good guy?

he was a good guy , but he was a vigilante if i would remember correctly , i used to watch it like 10-15 years ago

Sounds like Oswald Chesterfield "Penguin" Cobblepot from the DC Comics ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penguin_(comics) ) . But your questions sounds like the guy you are looking for is a good guy.

@Charmin: Exactly who I was thinking of.

@Hitman2847: You watched it 10-15 years ago, so 1990s. Was it new then, or were they repeats?

well i don't know that since our national tv would stream repeats some times but i assume it was new , or at most 2 -3 years old , and i mentioned he wears a cape and also carries a cane, has no hats , with a monocle , he is tall and thin , and he is the protagonist , and a vigilante

and there was a reporter , a female reporter , showing interest in him and his work, though i can't confirm there was a relationship or just appreciation , since our national tv sencors such matters :| which is pretty stupid

You might mean Arsene Lupin:

Arsène Lupin is a gentleman thief who appears in a series of detective and crime novels by the French writer Maurice Leblanc. The character has also appeared in a number of non-canonical sequels and numerous film, television (such as Night Hood), stage play, and comic book adaptations.

He was the protagonist of an animated Canadian show called Night Hood from 1996-1997 where he had a cape, a monocle and a cane, as well as a female reporter as a sidekick:


exactly , i always misremembered him to be older because of the dubbed voice , i can't tell for sure but they may have changed the name while dubbing , it is pretty common here to change everything , but anyway thanx soo much , you're master of TV :D
